# Pymongo return data without _id

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, pymongo

As the title says, how can I `find()` in my mongo all the data but without the `_id` index in the list.

Of course I can drop it later like:

```
for i in data:
   del i['_id']
```

But is there a more elegant solution without needing that loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you're looking for projections:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projections

Something like this should do it:

```
db.test.find(query,{"_id":0})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like ?

```
data = [dict(zip([f for f in e if '_id' not in f], e.values())) for e in data]
```

Although, I wouldn't use it, as it is not clear at all